# Trying to make image in table clickable on Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, style

I have a visualforce page with a table with images as follows:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!List_of_images}" var="Rlist" styleClass="box" >     
<apex:column headerValue="Pic" styleClass="P_image" value="{!Rlist.Pic_in_db}"/> 
</apex:dataTable>
```

I'm trying to make images that appear in the rows clickable. The link on the record should be obtained similarly to the list of images.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the column [facet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm?search_text=datatable) for the column header and explicitly configure the body.

E.g.

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!List_of_images}" var="Rlist" styleClass="box" >     
<apex:column headerValue="Pic" styleClass="P_image" value=""/>
    <apex:column styleClass="P_image">
        <apex:facet name="header">Pic</apex:facet>
        <a href="{!Rlist.LINK_IN_DB}"><apex:outputField value="{!Rlist.Pic_in_db}"/></a>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks. This seems to work on my VF page but for the oddest reason, when I display the VF page on a SF site, it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: What does not work? The link or the image or both? Could you describe it a bit more specific? Thanks